# Automatically open new query in adjacent window

Tags: sql-server

When I open a new query (File > New > Query with Current Connection) it opens in the same window as the Object Explorer. I have to then drag it over to put it in a window next to the Object Explorer..
How do I get it to automagically get it to open the window next to the Object Explorer?

[image]

Comment: Pin it to the window

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. In the screenshot I show, I think what I am doing is pinning it to the window. I want this to open automatically as an adjacent window when I do File > New > Query with Current Connection

Comment: The pin which @AlLelopath mentions is on the top right of the window's tab (i.e. icon of a drawing pin after the "SQLQuery..." text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the editor that's wrong, but the Object Explorer.  i.e. Your object explorer is in the main pane rather than the side pane.

Click and drag the object explorer pane to the left docking point.
After this it should remain to the left of any query windows which you open (always in the main pane).

Comment: I came across this issue today. I don't know why I would ever want the object explorer and the query results in the same window.